# Where can I find rules for firing a Ballista?

Tags: dnd-4e, house-rules

More specifically I'm looking for rules for a ship mounted ballista for my players in a 4th Ed. game.

I haven't been able to find anything in any of the books, the closest to anything in print is the weapons on the *Neverwinter's Pride* in the current Lair Assault.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to the D&D online compendium, there are some stat blocks for an Arcane Ballista <sup>[DDI](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/monster.aspx?id=1029)</sup> in Dungeon Magazine 155, page(s) 68.

Also there's an entry for Trebuchet and Crew <sup>[DDI](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/monster.aspx?id=4145)</sup>, Dungeon Magazine 170, page(s) 96.

I'm not sure how useful those are for ship-to-ship combat, though. Look deeper in the D&D message boards - there's a bunch of stuff hiding in there about homebrew ship-to-ship combat - especially between planeships. Specifically the [Iomandra and the Dragon Sea](http://community.wizards.com/wiki/Dnd%3aIomandra/Variant_Ship_Rules) variant ship rules.

Excerpt:

> ### Shipboard Weapons
>
> Shipboard weapons can be attacked independently of the ship they're on, and unlike ships they are not immune to melee and ranged attacks from creatures. A shipboard weapon typically has the following statistics: hp 80, AC 25, Fortitude 25, Reflex 0.
>
> A standard shipboard weapon requires a crew of two to operate: one to load and aim the weapon (standard action) and one to fire and reset it (standard action). The range is given in 100-foot squares (as opposed to 5-foot squares).
>
> **Ballista (500 gp)**: Ranged 5/10; +15 vs. AC (+13 while the ship is bloodied). Hit: 3d10 damage.
>
> **Catapult (500 gp)**: Ranged 10/20; +13 vs. AC (+11 while the ship is bloodied). Hit: 5d10 damage.
>
> Magical variants of standard shipboard weapons are also available.
>
> Magical weapons deal +5 damage per enhancement bonus on a hit, and they often have rider effects such as ongoing damage, damage on a miss, or some other effect. Some magical variants require ammunition, while others don't. Here are some examples of magical shipboard weapons:
>
> **+1 flameshot ballista (Level 10; 5,000 gp)**: Ranged 5/10; +16 vs. AC (+14 while the ship is bloodied). Hit: 3d10 + 5 fire damage, and ongoing 5 fire damage (save ends).
>
> **+2 thundershot ballista (Level 15; 25,000 gp)**: Ranged 5/10; +17 vs. AC (+15 while the ship is bloodied). Hit: 3d10 + 10 thunder damage, and the target ship loses 1 action on its next turn.
>
> **+1 shrapnel catapult (Level 10; 5,000 gp)**: Ranged 10/20; +14 vs. AC (+12 while the ship is bloodied). Hit: 5d10 + 5 damage, and roll 2d6:
>   On doubles, the target ship loses a number of crew equal to the highest die result.
>
> **+2 splintershot catapult (Level 15; 25,000 gp)**: Ranged 10/20; +15 vs. AC (+13 while the ship is bloodied). Hit: 5d10 + 10 damage. Miss: 15 damage.